# Can I use postgres_fdw without foreign tables defined?

Tags: postgresql, dblink

I have a production database "PRODdb1", with a read-only user account. I have a need to query(select statement) this database and insert the data into a secondary database named "RPTdb1". I originally planned to just create a temp table in PRODdb1 from my select, but permissions are the issue.

I've read abut dblink & postgres_fdw, but are either of these a solution for my issue? I wouldn't be creating foreign tables because my SELECT is joining many tables from PRODdb1, so I'm unfamiliar if postgres_fdw would still be an option for my use case.

Another option would be any means of getting the results of the SELECT to a .CSV file or something. My main blocker here is that I only have a read-only user to work with, but no way around that issue.

Comment: Maybe the best approach is to solve the permissions issues.  Can you expand on what those are?  Does the admin of PRODdb1 not wish to cooperate with you, or do you just not know how to go about carrying out that cooperation?

Answer (score 3):

`postgres_fdw` is definitely the better way. As you have read-only access to the production database, you can setup a FDW on your test (secondary) database provided you have superuser access to that (secondary) server. Or at least someone who can install the extension and setup the foreign server. Once those two things are there, you can proceed with a regular user.

One thing to keep in mind: if you do use the FDW, any select on the foreign table (in your test server) will generate some load on the production server. Whether or not that is acceptable only you can know.

---

> *my SELECT is joining many tables from PRODdb1*

If you join multiple *foreign* tables in a single statement those joins will be pushed down to the foreign server and evaluated there (at least with the Postgres 10 and I think 9.6 as well) only the result of the join will be sent back to the calling server.

---

Another option is to use `pg_dump` to copy the data from your production server to your test server.

```
pg_dump --host=prodserver --dbname=prod_db --table=public.some_table --file=some_table.sql --no-owner
```

That will export the data for `some_table` into a SQL script, including the necessary `CREATE TABLE` statement.

You can then run that SQL script through `psql` to import the data into your test server:

```
psql --host=testserver --dbname=test_db --file=test_table.sql
```

If you already have the table definition in your test server, then you might want to use `--data-only` for pg_dump to skip that part.

That will be faster than trying to generate some CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

> I wouldn't be creating foreign tables because my SELECT is joining
>   many tables from PRODdb1, so I'm unfamiliar if postgres_fdw would
>   still be an option for my use case.

You could ask PRODdb1 to create a view for you, then define your foreign table over that view.

Barring that, you can define foreign tables for every needed table in PRODdb1, possibly using [IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-importforeignschema.html) to automate it, then create your view or materialized view over those tables.